# Leibniz and Newton Chain Rule confusion

Tags: calculus

So say that we have chain of functions: f(g(x)). Now, if I was to differentiate with respect to x, my Leibniz notation intuition tells me to look for the rate of change of f with respect to g ($\Delta$f/$\Delta$g) times the rate of change g with respect to x ($\Delta$g/$\Delta$x). Or when lim $\Delta$x->$0$, $dz/dx=df/dg*dg/dx$. In newton's notation though, this is written as $f'(g(x))*g'(x)$. But this is merely stating that we take the derivative of f at g(x), not examining the fact that we observe the rate of change of $f$ with respect to $g(x)$ So therefore, shoudn't these notations not be completely different things? I feel like I missing something really fundamental here.

Comment: $f(x + h) \approx f(x) + f'(x)h,$ and  $f(g(x+h)\approx f(g(x) + g'(x)h) \approx f(g(x)) + f'(g(x)) g'(x) h$

Comment: I think it should be $f'(g(x+h))$ at the end right?

Comment: No.. $\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {f(g(x+h) - f(g(x))}{h} = \lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {f(g(x) +f'(g(x))g'(x)h - f(g(x))}{h} = f'(g(x))g'(x)$

Comment: $\Delta f/\Delta g$ means: How much does $f(g(x))$ change when $g(x)$ changes by a small amount? That is, we replace $g(x)$ with $g(x)+\delta$, then consider $\frac{f(g(x)+\delta)-f(g(x))}{\delta}$ as $\delta\to 0$. It doesn't matter that $g(x)$ depends on $x$ and that the investigated change of $g(x)$ ultimately comes from a change of $x$ (for that is covered by $\Delta g/\Delta x$)